# How localized is the effect of burning a Bonfire Ascetic?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Does using a Bonfire Ascetic raise the difficulty of the ENTIRE named area or only the area immediately around that bonfire. For example:

> The Lost Bastille has two bonfires that cater to the same boss fight and then a third bonfire after that boss that is still in the Bastille fast travel menu but is actually on the path to the next boss.

Will using an Ascetic at any of those three bonfires have the same effect on the entire area or will it only affect its portion and in this case only specific bonfires respawn the boss fight.

Comment: I've also noticed some oddities in White Soapstone Signs in Lost Bastille. I have seen summon signs in areas even though I have already killed the closest boss to the bonfire. The areas seem to be almost Worldwide (the main images in the travel[warp] screen), not bonfire specific. It seems probable that these are the same boundries.

Comment: Educated guess: when you are in the travel menu, the bonfire intensity is listed per bonfire, rather than per major area. That would make me believe the affected region is relatively small, rather than an entire area. However, I've yet to even toss one in anywhere to see what it does or how it affects that menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't affect the entire named area. It only affects the area between the bonfire on which the ascetic is used and the next bonfire. All enemies after the next bonfire will not be affected. For example, the first Aldia's keep bonfire will affect the rats outside the keep, the black phantom within the keep, the mirror knight enemies, the ogre and the giant basilisk but will not effect any enemies beyond that point as they all fall within the vicinity of the second bonfire, despite all the enemies beyond that point still belonging to Aldia's Keep. If you used an ascetic on the second bonfire, then all the aforementioned enemies would not be affected, and only the enemies between the second bonfire and the boss (including the boss, as the boss is 'associated' with the second bonfire) will be affected. I know it's a poor explanation, but hopefully it gave you an idea as to how the mechanic works.

Comment: I hope a list or map of these zones comes out at some points but this does answer my question. I am curious about areas like Lost Bastille (unless it is just unique) where two bonfires cater to the same enemies.

Comment: How many times can you use it on a single bonfire though. I've killed the giant lord I've 20 times only because each time I've killed him I get over 300k souls a pop and he's very easy to kill. I just wanna know how many times you can use it on a single bonfire

Answer (score 0):

Bonfire intensity is capped out at 99, though enemy difficulty is capped at 8, so once you get to intensity 8, every time you do it after it won't get any harder and you won't get any more souls than the last time you did it, all the way up to 99.

Comment: Praise the sun!